# Почему не меняется значение элемента массива при forEach

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дан массив:

```
const arr =  [1, 2, 3]
```

Задача: увеличить значение каждого элемента на 1
Почему этот код не работает? -

```
arr.forEach(el => {
  el += 1
})
```

а работает этот -

```
arr.forEach((el, i) => {
  arr[i] += 1
})
```

Comment: в почему он должен менять? в доках написано что он должен менять?

Answer (score 4):

`arr[i]` - это прямое изменение элемента массива по его индексу

сам `el` - это элемент массива, но он передаётся не по ссылке, поэтому он никак не влияет на то, что остаётся в массиве. Если бы элементом был объект, который изменяется по ссылке - другое дело..Но в данном случае идёт итерация примитивным типом, который неизменяемый

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const result = arr.map((el) => (el += 1));
console.log(result);
```

Объяснение:
Метод map в JavaScript позволяет применить заданную функцию для каждого элемента массива.

При этом метод не изменяет исходный массив, а возвращает изменённый.

Таким образом мы применяем этот метод к исходному массиву, и итерируя каждый элемент прибавляем единицу.

Таким образом получится:

```
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```